# Choosing different header file depending on instructions from Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, header-files, code-organization

I am trying to reorganize someone's code and I seem to have hit a wall.
I have a function `int fnc()` in `fnc.c` that is called by either `main1.c` or `main2.c`. An executable is compiled from either `main1.c` or `main2.c` using a makefile:

```
main1: main1.o fnc.o
    gcc main1.o fnc.o -o main1.x

main2: main2.o fnc.o
    gcc main2.o fnc.o -o main2.x

main1.o: main1.c
    gcc -c main1.c

main2.o: main2.c
    gcc -c main2.c

fnc.o:
    gcc -c fnc.c
```

The only problem is, there are two header files `header1.h` and `header2.h` to be included in the preamble of `fnc.c` **depending on whether main1.x or main2.x is compiled**:

```
#include "header1.h"

int fnc(){
    // do stuff
}
```

Is it possible to select which header to be loaded depending on whether one types `make main1` or `make main2`?

Comment: Pass the corresponding definition via `-D` to the compiler. And in the source code check with `#ifdef`.

Comment: Why bother with separate compilation if you have to recompile `fnc.c` separately anyway?

Comment: @melpomene How can I do this without compiling `fnc.c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-D` compiler flag to define a symbol that will be visible to preprocessor. And then to check it with the preprocessor `#ifdef` directive. Such as:

Makefile:

```
main1: main1.o fnc1.o
    gcc main1.o fnc1.o -o main1.x

main2: main2.o fnc2.o
    gcc main2.o fnc2.o -o main2.x

main1.o: main1.c
    gcc -c main1.c

main2.o: main2.c
    gcc -c main2.c

fnc1.o:
    gcc -o fnc1.o -c fnc.c -DCONFIG1

fnc2.o:
    gcc -o fnc2.o -c fnc.c -DCONFIG2
```

And your source:

```
#ifdef CONFIG1
#include "header1.h"
#elif defined(CONFIG2)
#include "header2.h"
#else
#error "blah"
#endif

int fnc(){
    // do stuff
}
```

- Note - this is neither tested nor an optimal solution. Just giving the idea

Comment: You could also do it "statically": Put `#include "header1.h"` `#include "fnc.c"` in `fnc1.c`, and `#include "header2.h"` `#include "fnc.c"` in `fnc2.c`. Then put the usual rules for `fnc1.c` and `fnc2.c` in your Makefile.

Comment: @melpomene Maybe worth to be an additional answer.

Comment: Thanks. Should there be a space between `-D` and `CONFIG1`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate No space needed.

Comment: @melpomene I'm trying to merge different copies of `fnc.c` so that whenever I make a modification to one of them, I don't have to go back and modify `fnc2.c`, etc.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate That's what my solution achieves. Why would you need to modify `fnc2.c`? It's only two lines.

Comment: @melpomene In other cases where `fnc2.c` would have more lines.

Comment: @melpomene [It's only two lines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611899/choosing-different-header-file-depending-on-instructions-from-makefile#comment88234311_50612026)  is certainly a result of OP nicely posting a [MCVE]

Comment: @sodiumnitrate `fnc2.c` is static. I don't understand what lines you would want to add. You'd only modify `fnc.c`.

Comment: @melpomene Oh, I see. Sorry I misunderstood -- I thought you were suggesting me to make a duplicate of `fnc.c` and call it `fnc2.c`. I think this is a good alternate answer.